# Independence in a geometric random variable - Am I doing this correctly?

Tags: probability, independence

> $X$ is a geometric r.v. with $p = 0.9$.
>   1. Conditioned on $\left\{3<X<10\right\}$, are $\left\{X=4\right\}$ and $\left\{X=5\right\}^C$ independent?
>   2. Find $E[X^2]$.

Attempt on #1:
$$\text{Independent if }\;P[AB]=P[A]\cdot P[B]$$
$$\left\{X=4\right\}\cap \left\{X=5\right\}^C = \left\{4\right\}\cap \left\{1,2,3,4,6,\dots\right\} = \left\{4\right\}$$
$$\text{Independent if }\;\frac{Pr(X=4)}{Pr(3<X<10)}\cdot\frac{Pr(X!=5)}{Pr(3<X<10)}=\frac{Pr(X=4)}{Pr(3<X<10)}$$
Answer is not independent.

Attempt on #2: 
\begin{align}E[X] &= \frac{1}{p}\\[0.2cm]
V[X] &= \frac{1-p}{p^2}\\[0.2cm]
E[X^2] &= V[X] + E[X] = \frac{0.1}{0.9^2} + \frac{1}{0.9}\end{align}

Comment: what does power of $X$ mean? second moment?

Comment: Yes, I believe my professor uses Power of X to denote: $E[X^2]$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Everything is correct, except that you missed somewhere a square in $E[X]$ \begin{align}Var(X)=E[X^2]-E[X]^2 \implies E[X^2]=Var(X)+E[X]^2\end{align} Hence\begin{align}E[X^2]&=\frac{1-p}{p^2}+\frac{1}{p^2}=\frac{0.1}{0.9^2}+\frac{1}{0.9^2}=\frac{1.1}{0.9^2}\end{align}

Comment: Got it, thanks!

Comment: @Jon Also, in the first part, since you are conditional on $3<X<10$, there is no need to write $\{X=5\}^c=\{1,2,3,4,6,\dots\}$. It is preferable to use this info and write $$\{X=5\}^c\mid 3<X<10=\{4,6,7,8,9\}$$

Comment: So my answer of not independent is correct?

Comment: Yes, it is correct.

Comment: @Jon If this answer is really helpful then don't forget to accept it.